# Android - Adding strings to hashmap

Tags: android, string, hashmap, buffer

I am currently reading a dictionary.png (which is a text file) into a buffer.
.png to make android think it is compressed.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
            try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
            String next;
            while ((next = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Add the string next to a map or whatever

            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            //Something nasty happened
            }
```

i'm not very familiar with `HashMaps` but i want to read the files from the dictionary into a hash map.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An example that does something similar to what you're asking about: [Using HashMap to map a String and int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922406/android-using-hashmap-to-map-a-string-and-int)